# Extra "zero" displayed on LCD when integer sent from PC to Arduino through serial port

Tags: lcd

Every time I send an integer from computer to Arduino an extra zero is displayed on the LCD connected to Arduino. I don't know the reason. Why?

Here is the code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int en = 2, rs = 3, d4 = 7, d5 = 6, d6 = 5, d7 = 4;
int a;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs,en,d4,d5,d6,d7);

void setup() {    
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.begin(16,2);

}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("Enter a number");
    while(Serial.available()==0){}
    a=Serial.parseInt();
    lcd.print(a);
}
```

The result is as follows:

- Enter a number
- When I enter the number `1`
- The result `10` is displayed instead of `1`

Comment: and what you get if you print `a` back to Serial Monitor?

Comment: It is a typical problem when reading the serial input. The more experienced arduino users do not use such a while-statement to wait for input and do not use the Serial.parseInt functions. You might send a linefeed as well, and the Serial.parseInt can not make a number from the linefeed and returns zero or perhaps it has a timeout and returns zero. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StreamParseInt

Comment: Is there any alternate command/function instead of using Serial.available() and Serial.ParseInt()???

Comment: @Jot, not true. parseInt has no problem with LF or any other character. we still don't know what is the value of a

Comment: @Juraj there could be a linefeed and there could be a timeout. I'm pretty sure the parseInt returns a normal number the first time and a zero with the next call to parseInt. In my opinion it is very obvious (even without actually testing it).

Comment: @Jot, true. Rizwan, add `while (Serial.read() != -1)'` after parseInt();

Comment: It is display related problem. You need to clear display field(s) before printing number.

Answer (score 3):

The `Serial.parseInt` returns zero when it can not find a number within a timeout. That timeout is default one second.
When a number is typed in the serial monitor, often a linefeed is added to it. That linefeed is read by `Serial.parseInt`. It can not make a number out of that and waits until the timeout and returns zero.

There is no way to tell if the `Serial.parseInt` returns zero because the number was zero, or if it returns zero because there was a timout.

You can try the next sketch to show the problem. Set the line ending in the serial monitor to linefeed or carriage return or both or nothing and see what happens.

```
int a;

void setup() {    
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Enter a number");
  while(Serial.available()==0){}
  a=Serial.parseInt();   // it returns zero with a linefeed !
  Serial.println(a);
}
```

The easiest way to fix this, is to use a number that is only a single digit. The function `isdigit` is used to check the incoming characters.

```
void setup() {    
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Enter a number (a single digit)");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int inChar = Serial.read();
    if (isdigit(inChar)) {
      int value = inChar - '0';
      Serial.println(value);
    }
  }
}
```

The `Serial.parseInt` is not completely useless, but the number zero can not be used. The next sketch ignores the input when `Serial.parseInt` returns zero.

```
void setup() {    
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Enter a integer, but not zero, with a linefeed at the end");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int value = Serial.parseInt();
    if (value != 0) {
      Serial.println(value);
      Serial.println("Enter a integer, but not zero, with a linefeed at the end");
    }
  }
}
```

To be able to allow to type the number 0, the `Serial.parseInt` can no longer be used. To avoid waiting and delays, every character is immediately put into a buffer. The sketch becomes larger, but there is no other way. Either use `Serial.parseInt` or do it right.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 40
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int index;

void setup() {    
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Enter a integer, with a linefeed at the end");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    bool ready = false;

    int inChar = Serial.read();
    buffer[index] = (char) inChar;
    index++;
    if (index >= BUFFER_SIZE) {
      index = BUFFER_SIZE - 1;
      ready = true;
    }

    if (inChar == '\n' || inChar == '\r') {
      ready = true;
    }

    if (ready) {
      if (isdigit(buffer[0]) || buffer[0] == '-') {
        buffer[BUFFER_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
        int value = atoi(buffer);
        Serial.println(value);
        Serial.println("Enter a integer, with a linefeed at the end");
      }
      index = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much..@Jot..                                                                                                        Thank to all of you..

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1. use lcd.println() instead of lcd.print().
2. Once you open the serial monitor, set it to "No line ending" instead of "newline".

if you do step 1 but miss step 2 the 0 will print on the next line.